# Operator overloading >> to complex number

Tags: c++

I would like to load and add complex number to my class. the testimony is that I do not know how to read a line of text

> This is my class

```
Class Complex
{
  double real;
  double imaginary; 
}
```

> This is overloading +

```
  Complex operator+(Complex & x)
    {
        Complex a;
        
        a.real = this->real + x.real;
        a.imaginary = this->imaginary + x.imaginary;
        
        return a;
    }
```

And I would like to load from input something like this :

> 2+3i + 5-4i

where first number is "2+3i" and second is "5-4i"

I've tried to overloading >> but it does't work

```
istream &operator >>(istream &s, Zespolone & x)
{
    static string line;
 
    getline(s, line, '+')>>x.real;
    getline(s, line, 'i')>>x.imaginary;
    
    
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the return value of `getline`. It returns the istream, not the string. It looks like you want to call `getline` to pull everything before the `+` into `line` and then pull the value of `line` into `x.real`, but what you're actually doing is extracting into `line`, then ignoring `line` and trying `s >> x.real`.

Comment: I would also suggest making `operator+` `const`-correct, by making its right-hand side a `const Complex&` and by making the method itself `const`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this (you would need to add error checks for invalid inputs):

```
class complex_t
{
public:
    complex_t operator + (complex_t & comp) {
        complex_t ncomp;
        ncomp.real = real + comp.real;
        ncomp.imag = imag + comp.imag;
        return ncomp;
    }
    double real {0};
    double imag {0};
};

class operator_t
{
public:
    uint8_t op {0};
};

std::stringstream & operator >> (std::stringstream & in, complex_t & complex)
{
    std::string line;
    char * p {nullptr};
    
    std::getline (in, line, ' ');

    complex.real = std::strtod(line.c_str(), &p);
    complex.imag = std::strtod(p, &p);
    return in;
}

std::stringstream & operator >> (std::stringstream & in, operator_t & op)
{
    std::string line;

    std::getline (in, line, ' ');
    op.op = line.c_str()[0];

    return in;
}

int main ()
{
    complex_t complex1;
    complex_t complex2;
    operator_t oper;
    std::stringstream input;
    std::string line;

    std::getline (std::cin, line);

    input.str (line);

    input >> complex1;
    input >> oper;
    input >> complex2;

    complex_t result {0};
    
    if (oper.op == '+') {
        result = complex1 + complex2;
    }

    std::cout << "Complex: "
              << complex2.real << " "
              << complex2.imag
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum: "
              << result.real << " "
              << result.imag
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```